# Populating child object from dapper stored procedure async

Tags: c#, dapper

How do I get Dapper to populate a 1:1 child object from a async stored procedure call?

I have a Premises object containing an Address object

```
public class Premises
{
    public int PremisesId { get; set; }
    public int EmployerId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1  { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine4 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine5 { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

I have a stored procedure with the following sql

```
SELECT 
    p.premisesId, p.employerId, 
    a.addressId, a.addressLine1, a.addressLine2,
    a.addressLine3, a.addressLine4, a.addressLine5
FROM 
    Premises p 
INNER JOIN 
    Address a ON p.addressId = a.addressId 
WHERE 
    p.premisesId = @premisesId
```

Calling the stored procedure with the following code:

```
Premises premises = await Connection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<Premises>("premisesGetById", new { premisesId }, Transaction, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

The `premisesId` and `employerId` map as expected but the address object is null.

Comment: I've managed to get splitOn working with a query, but can't work out how to do the same with an async stored procedure call.

Answer (score 0):

Manged to sort it. 
My issue stemmed from the fact there isn't an overloaded method of QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync that has the map parameter.

The solution was to use the QueryAsync method then call SingleOrDefault() on the returned IEnumerable

This can be wrapped into a single line

```
var premises = (await Connection.QueryAsync<Premises, Address, Premises>(
     sql:"premisesGetById",
     param: new { premisesId }, 
     map: (prem, address) => { prem.Address = address; return prem; },
     splitOn: "AddressId",
     transaction:Transaction,
     commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
   )).SingleOrDefault();
```

Thanks for the pointers. Hope this helps someone in the future.